# Transaction history API is not sending payer email address?

Tags: api, paypal, integration

I have requested for the transaction history by using paypal sync api and getting the successful response but response does not contain payer email address in payer_info object is this bug or i need some permissions to get the email address

Comment: It is always better to follow the documentation of your payment gateway.

Comment: email address is not marked as required inside payer_info according ot the API doc on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/sync/v1/#definition-payer_info but I'm not sure if it is a bug or a "feature"

Comment: i need to fetch the one year old transaction history and paypal sync API sdk is not available

Comment: thanks lrek i already found that email address is available in transaction but not getting that from API call